# How to network and connect docker containers with each other using just simple localhost?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-for-windows

So I have this in my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  api:
    image: api
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - "redis"
    links:
      - "redis"
```

But when I try accessing `localhost:6379` in the API container, can't connect error is thrown.

I tried `network_mode: host` but it's a Linux only solution and does not work on Docker on Windows.

What alternatives do I have on Windows?

Comment: `localhost` inside a container refers to the container itself. That's why the `api` container cannot reach the `redis` container. Try with the container names instead.

Comment: I have the whole project setup with `localhost`s with different ports and there's many containers and services that need to connect with each other over `localhost`. I was hoping for a `localhost` solution if there's one. :smile:

Comment: "_127.0.0.0/8 - This block is assigned for use as the Internet host loopback address. A datagram sent by a higher-level protocol to an address anywhere within this block loops back inside the host. This is ordinarily implemented using only 127.0.0.1/32 for loopback. As described in [RFC1122], Section 3.2.1.3, **addresses within the entire 127.0.0.0/8 block do not legitimately appear on any network anywhere.**_"

Answer (score 0):

in the `api` container you use connect using the `redis` hostname instead of `localhost`. so you should be connecting to `redis:6379` instead.

Comment: There's no way I can use `localhost:6379` - like with Linux's `network_mode: host`?

Comment: why do you need this?

Comment: I have the multiple projects setup to connect to each other with `localhost` for different services on different ports. I was able to do this in Linux but on Windows looks like there's no alternative.

Comment: you still did not specify as to why that's needed, you can still access the service from your host using the localhost port mappings, while the containers themselves communicate using the hostnames

Comment: Yes, the containers are setup to connect to, let's say `redis`, at `localhost:6379` and to `mongo` at `localhost:27017`.

Comment: I was looking to find a way to not change these URLs and be able to make the connection and I did not find any solutions.

Comment: hmm you could potentially change the `/etc/hosts` in the containers to look for different address instead, but this is [discouraged](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109247). normally, it's wise, when designing apps to use environmental variables as api endpoints. Only when they are missing, using `localhost` as a fallback

Comment: yes, I agree with @pandamakes, an excellent way to go about it would something like `redisUrl = env.get('REDIS_URL') or 'localhost:6379'` meaning that if it's not defined, it fallsback to localhost, so you could just as easily run the service outside of Docker as well, on your local machine

See: https://12factor.net/config

Answer (score 0):

From [Networking features in Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/):

> ## Known limitations, use cases, and workarounds
>
> #### I want to connect from a container to a service on the host
>
> The host has a changing IP address (or none if you have no network access). From 18.03 onwards our recommendation is to connect to the special DNS name `host.docker.internal`, which resolves to the internal IP address used by the host. This is for development purpose and will not work in a production environment outside of Docker for Windows.
>
> The gateway is also reachable as `gateway.docker.internal`.

Comment: Okay, so there's no way other than to change the URLs that I connect to from containers. :thumbs_up: